# MySQL:Select a table (for email) based on another tables data

Tags: php, mysql, database

Here is the issue: I have 4 tables in a DB. one is "calls" and the other 3 are the support teams "IT","Maintenance","Engineering". When a row is created in the "calls" table there is a field named" Support team" and there are 3 possible options for this field it, maintenance, and engineering. I need to be able to email these teams based on what team has been requested in the "calls" table. All of the email info is stored in the individual team's table. I hope this makes sense. If not I can diagram the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Create 3 string variables to go into support_team field of the calls table: it, maintenance, engineering.
Let the variables have the same name as the database tables it, maintenance and engineering.
After inserting a new record in the calls table, use this

```
$team = "Select calls.support_team from calls where id = $last_id ";
"Select * from $team ";
```

Where `$last_id` is the id of the recently inserted record in the calls table. 
Since `$team` gets the name of the tables: id, maintenance or engineering; the second line of code just gets the names of team members.

Answer (score 0):

Since the tables are limited you could do a bunch of left joins:

```
SELECT * FROM calls
LEFT JOIN team_it ON calls.`support team` = 'it' AND calls.id = team_it.id
... etc
```

I didn't know what the join conditions are, so I guessed the `calls.id = team_it.id`

If the three tables already have a "foreign key" to calls, you can just `left join` on that instead.

Comment: Thanks!!! I decided to make it easier on myself and create 3 coulmns in the "calls" table IT, Maintenance, and Engineering and setting them to deafult to "0" and "1" if that team was selected. Now if IT is true my script will email everyone in IT and like wise in the other departments. I will however go back adn try it the way you described for my own future reference.

Comment: @TimFowler No problem. But adding those 3 columns is not much different from the single column with three possible values *unless* a call can be present in all three support team tables.

Comment: Yes, calls can be made to any combonation of the teams, not just a single team

Comment: In that case you could just use the foreign key in each team table to simplify the left joins I proposed in my answer.